# POST different name field

Tags: php

I'm working on a survey where the user gets to create their question/answer and then displays it to the end user.  The issue I'm having is posting the `<input>` value to another page. Here's why:

```
<dt><label for='$row[question]'>$row[question]</label></dt>";

         if ($row['type'] == "1-5")
         {
            echo "<dd><input type='radio' name='$row[id]' value='1' />&nbsp;&nbsp;1
                      <input type='radio' name='$row[id]' value='2' />&nbsp;&nbsp;2
```

My **< inputs >** have a name that are not static. The id from the database is an auto number.

**How can I retrieve this on another page to execute it?**  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you can't use all numbers for the element name. Anyways, you need to foreach through $_POST and see if any keys match. It might be better to prepend it with something like, `"row_" . $row['id']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. Thanks anyways.

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
}
```